# Align Logo and Title on same line CSS

Tags: css, themes

How do I align the Logo and Title on same line? Right now the logo is above the title.

```
/***** Header *****/

.mh-header {
  background: #fff;
}

.mh-site-logo {
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.mh-header-text {
  margin: 5px 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.mh-header-title {
  font-size: 32px;
  font-size: 2rem;
  line-height: 1;
}

.mh-header-tagline {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #e64946;
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}
```

Comment: Could you paste the html code so that a better solution can be provided

Comment: Can you include your HTML as well so we know what we're looking at? Thanks.

Comment: Im using the mh lite theme.<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="mh-wrapper mh-clearfix">
 <div id="main-content" class="mh-loop mh-content" role="main"><?php
  mh_before_page_content();
  if (have_posts()) {
   if (is_home() && !is_front_page()) { ?>
    <header class="page-header">
     <h1 class="page-title">
      <?php single_post_title(); ?>
     </h1>
    </header><?php
   }
   mh_magazine_lite_loop_layout();
   mh_magazine_lite_pagination();
  } else {
   get_template_part('content', 'none');
  } ?>
 </div>
 <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>

Answer (score 0):

put the logo and title in the same div with a class ***wrapper*** element, then for this div element add this css styling

```
wrapper{ display: flex;}
```